# Vim on Solaris. Coloured syntax highlighting?

Tags: vim, colors, solaris, syntax-highlighting

I spend a lot of my time in vim, usually on some sort of debian/ubuntu OS. I've recently started playing with a Solaris 11 Express server and wondered if it's possible to enable coloured syntax-highlighting in vim.

I've copied a lot of my `vimrc` and `.bashrc` settings over from Ubuntu, and it works mostly how I like it. However, syntax highlighting on Solaris remains an odd sort of greyscale, rather than coloured.

The compile options in `vim --version` on both instances look to be similar, and the `vimrc` files are similar between both.

Is there anything I need configure or add to my installation to enable coloured syntax-highlighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your `TERM` environment variable to something else that supports more colors. I don't currently have access to a solaris host, but I think `xtermc` may be supported.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and wow, INSTANT fix. Thank you.